# Yii2 activerecord PHP get multiple join from 3 different Tables

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii2

I have 3 Models

```
class ModelA{
    public function getBs{
        return $this->hasMany(ModelB::className(), ["AID"=>"BID"]);
    }
}

class ModelB{
    public function getCs{
        return $this->hasMany(ModelC::className(), ["BID"=>"CID"]);
    }
}

class ModelC{

}
```

using yii2 activerecord I'd like to retrieve the relations of `ModelB, ModelC` tables joined with `ModelA`

I tried the following:

```
$a =  ModelA::find()
    ->joinwith("bs")
    ->joinwith("cs")
    ->where(["id"=>1])
```

I could get from this `$a->bs` but not `'$a->bs->cs'`,

I could have use some other way that would lazy load the data from db but I am looking for EagerLoading data from db

what am I doing wrong here ? Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's explained in the guide: [Lazy Loading and Eager Loading](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#lazy-eager-loading)

```
$a = ModelA::find()->with('bs.cs')->all();
```